# IQKeyboardManagerSwift pod install : How to implement Done button action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm using the following library (which helps to manage multiple textfields)

> pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 4.0'

My question is how would I got about to implement `done button action` in our viewController ?
I refer this [link](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/475). 
 
In IQUIView+IQKeyboardToolbar.swift file this method is available.

```
public func addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(_ target : AnyObject?, action : Selector) {

        addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(target, action: action, titleText: nil)
    }
```

but I don't understand how to implement in swift code.
Please help me..

Comment: For future you can use this https://objectivec2swift.com conversion tool. It converts objective-c into swift.

Comment: Ya, Thanks @Amanpreet

Answer (score 1):

You can call it on any textField object. for example

```
[textField1 addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget:@selector(doneAction:)];
/*! doneAction. */
-(void)doneAction:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButton
{
    //doneAction
}
```

Swift Version:

```
textField1.addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget(self, action: #selector(self.doneAction(_:)), shouldShowPlaceholder: true)

func doneAction(_ sender : UITextField!) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Please give the swift version of your code , that will be more helpful as the OP specifically asked for swift